# How to create a list of tuples from two specific columns of a csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples, multiple-columns

My csv file looks something like this:

```
{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id,begin,end,Character
18074,15,19,Tony
18120,39,46,Tony
18172,129,134,Clint
18217,175,180,Bucky
18202,245,249,Tony
18307,352,357,Bucky
18376,1297,1302,Steve
18421,1499,1504,Bruce
18489,1546,1553,Natasha
18527,1709,1712,Bucky
```

I would like to be able to create a list of tuples from the columns `begin` and `end`, starting from the second row, ignoring the title-row, of course.

So far I can create a list of tuples but for **all** rows and columns:

```
import csv
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
root_tk = tkinter.Tk()
root_tk.wm_withdraw()

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]

print(data)



root_tk.destroy()
root_tk.mainloop()
```

Current output:

```
[('{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id', 'begin', 'end', 'Character'), ('18646', '518', '520', 'Anakin'), ('18699', '982', '985', 'Jedi'), ('18714', '1018', '1020', 'Anakin'), ('18766', '1057', '1059', 'Anakin'),...
```

Desired output:

```
[(15, 19), (39,46), (129, 134), (175, 180)...]
```

How do I limit the output to those two columns, while ignoring the first row and create a list of tuples from them?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

I am now able to print the tuples I want, but I can't remove the first row from the output still.

Also, how do I convert the output from a string tuple to integer?

Comment: `tuple(line)[1:3]` ?

Comment: @krishna yeah, that's something I tried. It kinda works, but it still gives me the first row (the title row) and it prints the numerals as strings with parentheses. I edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and create tuples from columns you need

```
import csv

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data=[(int(line['begin']),int(line['end'])) for line in  csv.DictReader(f)]
    print data
```

output:

```
[(15, 19), (39, 46), (129, 134), (175, 180), (245, 249), (352, 357), (1297, 1302), (1499, 1504), (1546, 1553), (1709, 1712)]
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: This looks good! But as I mentioned in my edit above, I would also like the tuples to be numerals, and not strings under parentheses. Is it doable in your code?

Comment: @Waldkamel Modified . does this help?

Comment: Ah, awesome! Thank you! :) - If i'm not being annoying: is it possible to print out only unique tuples? Some of them are twice in the file...no stress if it's too much! :)

Comment: No worries . `set` is what you're looking for . 
`data  = list(set(data))` returns list with unique tuples

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pandas`

```
In [615]: df = pd.read_csv('eg.csv')

In [616]: [(begin, end) for _, begin, end, _ in df.values.tolist()]
Out[616]:
[(15, 19),
 (39, 46),
 (129, 134),
 (175, 180),
 (245, 249),
 (352, 357),
 (1297, 1302),
 (1499, 1504),
 (1546, 1553),
 (1709, 1712)]
```

If you want to use the `csv` module you can try

```
In [627]: with open('eg.csv', 'r') as f:
     ...:     csv_data = next(csv.reader(f), None)          # Skip first row
     ...:     data=[(int(line[1]), int(line[2])) for line in csv.reader(f) if line]
     ...:
```

Or without any imported modules at all

```
In [639]: with open('eg.csv', 'r') as f:
     ...:     f.readline()               # Skip first row
     ...:     data=[tuple(map(int, line.split(',')[1:3])) for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]
     ...:
```

Comment: For such a simple task, `pandas` is quite an overkill. Plus, it looks like OP is using only standard library tools.

Comment: Just an alternative way to do it